# Adding a different image to each list item from RSS

Tags: html, css, rss, listitem

I have a list item from RSS I used the zRSSFeed in particular. I would like to have a custom image on each of the list items. I'm presenting them in blocks or 3 in a row on normal width. Technically I guess I could target each one of them separately, I have no more than 6 of them, but I was wondering if there was a much better way to do it. It would be no problem if I could add some additional classes, but the HTML is generated by RSS. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Bit more info needed. Are you using jquery? You can probably just use CSS with ::before the li.

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm also using jQuery.

Comment: easily done, but post some of your code so we can help you